# Google+ Hangout Button Window Location

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-hangouts

So I was trying to embed the hangouts button within my website and realised that it opens a new window when the button is pressed through my website.

So my question is. Is it possible to set the location and size of the window relative to my screen. For example when the hangout button is pressed (through my website) is it possible for the window to open on the bottom left cornor of my screen ?

I read on several forums that is not possible to entirely embed hagouts into your website and needs to always open another window. Is this true ?﻿

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp..

```js
window.open(url, windowName, "height=200,width=200");
```

it helps you to open a new customzed window as per your request.

Comment: I am rendering the button through google+ api with the following code:

gapi.hangout.render('div', { 'render': 'createhangout', 'invites': [{'id' : pid, 'invite_type' : 'PROFILE'}], 'widget_size': 35  
});

The above code creates a windowed hangout with a specific person. I was wondering if there is anyway to manipulate this window.